# How can I use a small Shimano BB on any frame?

Tags: frames, shimano, bottom-bracket, fixed-gear

I have a [Shimano BB-ES25 bottom bracket](http://www.wickedcycles.co.uk/shimano-bb-es25-bottom-bracket-octalink-68-126-1350-p.asp) and 45T crankset that was removed from a Giant-CRX City with an eccentric hub (it had Shimano Alfine internal hub gears).

They have literally never been used, and the bike they came out of has since been stolen.

Now I'm planning a custom fixed gear bike build, and hoping to re-use these parts, since I'm on a shoestring budget.

**What parts do I need to use this BB in a frame that expects a standard sized BB?**

Also, am I correct that, since this is designed for an eccentric hub, I should be able to use any frame for my fixie, instead of being restricted to ones with a horizontal dropout?

Comment: Shimano likes to make the "fixed" cup part of the cartridge.  For this reason, unless that cup will thread into your BB, you probably can't use the cartridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link says that the BB you have is a 68mm shell width, which is standard ISO/British thread.  That's going to fit a lot of bikes.  It is not designed specifically for eccentric bottom brackets.  To use the item you linked to in a single/fixed speed bike you would need horizontal (or at least diagonal) dropouts.

If that was part of an eccentric BB assembly, you would also have had something sort of like this:

http://www.jensonusa.com/Misc-Frame-Sup-Bushnell-Eccentric-BB

that it would have gone into, and then that eccentric BB would have gone into an oversized/eccentric bottom bracket shell that was part of the bike frame.

If you still have that eccentric bottom bracket, then you might be able to go looking for a frame with a same-size eccentric bottom bracket shell that it would fit into.  Such a frame would then have vertical dropouts, because there's no reason to have an eccentric shell and horizontal dropouts in the same frame -- don't need to solve the chain-tensioning problem twice.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The bike it came out of (Giant CRX-City) did have an eccentric BB similar to the one you posted. I was hoping to find another Eccentric BB that would fit in commonly available frames. Does that exist?

Comment: Probably, but not terribly common to see frames sold with eccentric bb shells.  Why not just buy a horizontal dropout frame that has a standard bottom bracket shell?

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to guage how common they are. Horizontal dropout frames aren't all that common either, at least not where I live. I was hoping there was some eccentric bb that would fit in a standard road bike frame.